# Android Studio Asset Studio Preview Rendering Error

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, assets

I am trying to edit my launcher icon & am getting the following error
'Preview rendering error: x lies outside raster'

The icons do not load

I'm creating flutter projects and the problem persists upon making a new project

I'm not sure how to grab any more info if you guys know so I can provide more I'd appreciate the input

[Screencap Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7iY0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Android API library might not be linked to your flutter project. I faced the same error and I fixed by following the below mentioned steps:

1. File > Project Structure > Under Project Settings/Project > Set Project SDK to Android API 29 Platform
   [image]
   [image]
2. There should be a notification stating there is an invalid item in the dependencies list under Project Structure/Problems. If there is, go to Project Structure > Under Project Settings/Modules > select app_name_android > Dependencies tab > choose the latest "Android API 29 Platform" in the Module SDK box.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
3. Update GradleException() to FileNotFoundException() under android/app/build_gradle since it's not supported in the Java version of Android API 29

That's it! You should notice the Android API 29 Platform is now visible under External Libraries. That means it is now linked to your project.